# Emulator deleted my all application on restarting....why?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am newbie to android development.yesterday I created an application and installed that appliaction into emulator. It was working fine. I ran it many times.

But today when I launched emulator, It doesn't have any application installed by me.
I dont know where is my application gone.I cant figure out what happened.

Please help me..can anybody know what is problem??

Thanks and Regards
Vaibhav Tyagi

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that when you launch the emulator via the AVD Manager, there is a checkbox which allows you to 'wipe user data' on the emulator. That should be unset.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
But I didn't change anything.